# How to base64 encode openssl generated key pem files?

Tags: java, encryption, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I generate the private key

```
openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048
```

Then I generate the public key from the private key

```
openssl rsa -in private_key.pem -out public_key.pem -outform PEM -pubout
```

I would like to hard-code these keys into my java program. And I want to use it with the `PrivateKey` and `PublicKey` classes in java.

My initial thought is I have to base64 encode the .pem files. Then there must be some java methods to convert the base64 encoded keys to their respective `PrivateKey` and `PublicKey` classes.

Thoughts?

Openssl CLI does have the base64 encode command but ....

There's the usual:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
keyinfo
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Do I need to parse these away before doing the base64 encode?

Comment: I think the contents of that block is already base64 encoded.  You should remove the BEGIN and END lines before base64 decoding them.  Big Note:  It may be fine to include your public key in your Java program, however you should not directly include your private key.  See here for some more insight:   https://rammic.github.io/2015/07/28/hiding-secrets-in-android-apps/

Comment: [Load RSA public key from file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11410770/608639), [How to read .pem file to get private and public key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11787571/608639), [Getting RSA private key from PEM BASE64 Encoded private key file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7216969/608639), [How can I read a BouncyCastle private key PEM file using JCA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14228282/608639), etc.