# how to decode PEM-encoded SSL_CLIENT_CERT header value sent from apache in java

Tags: java, apache, parsing, encoding, client-certificates

I'm sending a PEM-encoded client certificate in a HTTP header via SSL_CLIENT_CERT varialbe from apache2 to jboss5 and in my application I'm reading the value of this header and I try to decode it in java but I get an unsuported encoding exception

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: Unsupported encoding
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:109)
```

my apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName a.localhost
ProxyPass / http://b.localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://b.localhost:8080/

SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLOptions +ExportCertData +StdEnvVars
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

SSLVerifyClient optional
SSLVerifyDepth 1
SSLCertificateFile C:\Users\user\ssh\4pm.si_wildcard.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile C:\Users\user\ssh\4pm.si_wildcard.key
SSLCACertificateFile C:\Users\user\ssh\ca_cert_bundle.crt
RequestHeader set X-ClientCert %{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}s

ErrorLog "C:/Apps/wamp/logs/4pm-error-ssl.log"
CustomLog "C:/Apps/wamp/logs/4pm-access-ssl.log" common


</VirtualHost>
```

my java code :

```
 String certStr = certStr = JSFUtil.getRequest().getHeader("x-clientcert");

 try {
        Certificate cert = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(certStr.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    } catch (CertificateException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Tnx to owlstead for the hint, which drives me to the solution.

**The solution for this problem is:**

you need those imports:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.jboss.util.Base64;

public static X509Certificate parseCertificate(String _headerName, HttpServletRequest _request) throws CertificateException{

    String certStr = _request.getHeader("x-clientcert");
    //before decoding we need to get rid off the prefix and suffix
    byte [] decoded = Base64.decode(certStr.replaceAll("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", "").replaceAll("-----END CERTIFICATE-----", ""));

    return (X509Certificate)CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PEM is base 64 encoding with a header and footer line. You cannot just perform *character-encoding* on the text using UTF-8. You need to [*decode* the PEM itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787571/how-to-read-pem-file-to-get-private-and-public-key).

Comment: Tnx for the hint I was trying to decode it with some adobe Base46 lib but it was not working then I swtched to org.jboss.util.Base64 and it worked ... I will update my question with the solution and marked your answer as correct

Comment: Be warned that receiving a certificate chain *could* (I'm not sure) be part of the posibilities (i.e. a client certificate and one or more intermediate CA-certificates)