# X509Certificate2 PublicKey can't get the right value

Tags: c#, .net, dns

hope you can help me. 
i'm using X509Certificate2 and X509Store to write a certificate (.pfx) into X509Store.
Then i go to the dns and request the publicKey token from it, once it reply i see the publicKey i get is in Base64 wheres when i find the proper X509Certificate2 from the X509Store i cant find any way to represent publicKey to match the one i get from the dns.

how can i get the base64 representation of the public key to look like dns?!

I have already tried to use:
byte[] arrBytes = certificate2.GetPublicKey();
and 
byte[] arrBytes = certificate2.PublicKey.EncodedKeyValue.RawData

both are not giving me the same base64 as the one i get from dns,
or am i missing some thing?!

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer in this two threads:

[C# Export Private/Public RSA key from RSACryptoServiceProvider to PEM string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23734792/c-sharp-export-private-public-rsa-key-from-rsacryptoserviceprovider-to-pem-strin)

and

[C# RSA Public Key Output Not Correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406888/c-sharp-rsa-public-key-output-not-correct/28407693#28407693)

Take **ExportPublicKey** function from second link and use:

```
 string st1 = ExportPublicKey((RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate2.PublicKey.Key);
```

where certificate2 is **X509Certificate2** object from your **X509Store** .
Got that working for me!
:)