# Generate ED25519 keys for ssh connection with Bouncy Castle c#

Tags: c#, ssh, bouncycastle, ed25519

I have to generate che keys in ED25519 for SSH connection. I'm able to create the public and the private keys but not the key for ssh. Is there anyone who can help me?
Below my C# code.

Thanks

```
IAsymmetricCipherKeyPairGenerator gen;
KeyGenerationParameters param;
gen = new Ed25519KeyPairGenerator();
param = new Ed25519KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom());
gen.Init(param);
var keyPair = gen.GenerateKeyPair();

TextWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();
PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(textWriter);
pemWriter.WriteObject(keyPair.Private);
pemWriter.Writer.Flush();
                 
var privateKeyParam = keyPair.Private;

textWriter = new StringWriter();
pemWriter = new PemWriter(textWriter);
pemWriter.WriteObject(keyPair.Public);
pemWriter.Writer.Flush();

result.PrivateKey = textWriter.ToString();
result.PublicKey = textWriter.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The similar answer is posted here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60354942/7799305

Maybe try using this library [SshKeyGenerator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SshKeyGenerator/)

Heres the GitHub repo:
https://github.com/ShawInnes/SshKeyGenerator

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With RSA I'm able to generate che key but not with EC25519