# Generate RSA private key .pem file

Tags: java, openssl, rsa, pem

Basically I have private key `Priv (d,n)` of RSA where `M= Cd mod(n)`.

I know the numbers (`d` and `n`), and I have the public key PEM file.
I want to generate the private key PEM file to use for decrypt a message using OPENSSL.

Anyone know how to do this (in Java, if it's possible)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read .pem file to get private and public key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787571/how-to-read-pem-file-to-get-private-and-public-key)