# How to use RSAPublicKey and RSAPrivateKey classes in Java?

Tags: java, jwt, rsa

I am trying to use [Java JWT] library(https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt) to generate JWT and I require to make instances of private key and public key i.e. RSAPrivateKey and RSAPublicKey.

```
//RSA
RSAPublicKey publicKey = //Get the key instance
RSAPrivateKey privateKey = //Get the key instance
Algorithm algorithmRS = Algorithm.RSA256(publicKey, privateKey);
```

How do I create the instances of RSAPrivateKey and RSAPublicKey?

I have created .pem files using `OpenSSL` (if that helps) but I am not able to use that too.

Comment: You need to generate a KeyPair so the PrivateKey can be used to decode the PublicKey. Check out this link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/step2.html

Comment: @FattySalami The link you provided gives a method to generate instances of classes PublicKey and PrivateKey but I need instances of the classes RSAPublicKey and RSAPrivateKey. Please see to it. It will be very helpful if you provide a code snippet or some explanation.Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

First create the KeyPairGenerator to create the KeyPairs.

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
```

This will give you a KeyPairGenerator using RSA. Next you initialize the generator with the amount of bytes you want it to use and then create the KeyPair.

```
kpg.initialize(1024);
KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
```

Get the PublicKey and PrivateKey from the KeyPair kp using their Getters and than because RsaPublicKey is just a a SubClass of Key and we made these keys with RSA we can safely cast the PublicKey and PrivateKey classes to RSAPublicKey and RSAPrivateKey

```
RSAPublicKey rPubKey = (RSAPublicKey) kp.getPublic();
RSAPrivateKey rPriKey = (RSAPrivateKey) kp.getPrivate();
```

Comment: That code generares a new keypair.  If you want to use an existing keypair, just load it from a keystore (faster) or from a pem file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787571/how-to-read-pem-file-to-get-private-and-public-key/14177328