# Java Decrypt with NodeJS Encrypt <RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING> padding and <sha256> oaepHash

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

I need to decrypt some information coming from an external service built with NodeJS.
This service ask for a RSA (2048) public key in pem format in base64, in order to encrypt the information.

I am creating the key pair in Java:

```
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
    PublicKey pubkey = kp.getPublic();
    PrivateKey privkey = kp.getPrivate();

    String pemPublicString = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n";
    pemPublicString = pemPublicString+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(pubkey.getEncoded())+"\n";
    pemPublicString = pemPublicString+"-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";
    
    String pemPrivateString = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
    pemPrivateString = pemPrivateString+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(privkey.getEncoded())+"\n";
    pemPrivateString = pemPrivateString+"-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
    
    //Send to node js service
    String base64publickey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(pemPublicString.getBytes());

    //Store for decrypting
    String base64privatekey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(pemPrivateString.getBytes());
```

The external service is encrypting the information as follows and is returning the bytes:

```
  crypto.publicEncrypt(
  {
    key: publicKey,
    padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING,
    oaepHash: "sha256",
  },
    dataToEncrypt
  );
```

I am trying to decrypt the information in Java as follows:

```
    public String decrypt(String payload, String privateKey){
      byte [] ciphertext = payload.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      Cipher oaepFromInit = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding");
      OAEPParameterSpec oaepParams = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", new 
      MGF1ParameterSpec("SHA-1"), PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
      oaepFromInit.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getRSAPrivateKeyFrom(privateKey), oaepParams);
      byte[] pt = oaepFromInit.doFinal(ciphertext);
      return new String(pt, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    private PrivateKey getRSAPrivateKeyFrom(String content) {
      byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(content);
      String decodedString = new String(decodedBytes);
      Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
      PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new StringReader(decodedString));
      JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC");
      Object object = pemParser.readObject();
      PrivateKey k = converter.getPrivateKey((PrivateKeyInfo) object);
      return k;
   }
```

Now I am getting a BadPadding Exception, any idea of what could be the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try `MGF1ParameterSpec("SHA-256")`? Java is a bit specific in that it doesn't use the same hash for both the MGF and the label. Usually if only one hash is given in a library it is used for both. If it doesn't work, try `"SHA-1"` as first parameter...

Comment: Your RSA private key is not correctly encoded, Java uses PKCS#8 as default encoding, and that should be just `PRIVATE KEY` in PEM, not `RSA PRIVATE KEY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code does not show how the NodeJS code exports the ciphertext. The following line in `decrypt()` of the Java code:

```java
 byte[] ciphertext = payload.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

implies that you have used a Utf-8 encoding. This is a common mistake that corrupts the ciphertext (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9098905)). Instead of Utf-8, apply a [binary-to-text enncoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding), such as Base64.

The export of the ciphertext would then be done in NodeJS with:

```js
var chiphertextBase64 = ciphertext.toString('base64');
```

and the import in Java with:

```java
import java.util.Base64;
...
byte[] ciphertext = Base64.getDecoder().decode(payload);
```

---

In the NodeJS code, OAEP ([RSAES-OAEP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-7.1)) is specified as padding. [`crypto.publicEncrypt()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_publicencrypt_key_buffer) applies with the parameter `oaepHash` the **same** digest for both, the OAEP and MGF1 digest. `oaepHash: "sha256"` thus specifies SHA256 for *both* digests.
In contrast, Java allows separate (and different) specification of OAEP and MGF1 digests. While SHA256 is used for the OAEP digest in `decrypt()`, SHA1 is applied for the MGF1 digest. The latter is inconsistent with the NodeJS code and needs to be changed to SHA256:

```java
OAEPParameterSpec oaepParams = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", new MGF1ParameterSpec("SHA-256"), PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
```

This bug was already suspected in the 1st comment by Maarten Bodewes.

---

In the posted code, the PEM encoded `pemPublicString` and `pemPrivateString` keys are Base64 encoded as `base64publickey` and `base64privatekey` respectively. This is not necessary because the body of a PEM encoded key is already Base64 encoded and header and footer consist of ASCII characters. A second Base64 encoding thus brings no advantage, but the disadvantage that the key data is unnecessarily enlarged (Base64 overhead: 33%, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)). On the other hand, if the service expects a double Base64 encoded public key, you must comply.

When generating keys, the posted Java code implicitly uses the PKCS#8 format for the private key. You can verify this with `privkey.getFormat()`, which will output `PKCS#8`. The associated header for PKCS#8 is `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and Footer `-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`. Both the header and footer you are currently using belong to a PEM encoded PKCS#1 private key and are thus inconsistent with the key data. This issue has already been addressed in the 2nd comment by Maarten Bodewes.

By the way, a PKCS#8 key can easily be imported without *BouncyCastle* using [`PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/security/spec/PKCS8EncodedKeySpec.html). For this only header, footer and line breaks have to be removed and the rest has to be Base64 decoded (DER encoding), s. e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27621696).